# Extract RCP perspective layout back into IDE

Tags: eclipse, rcp, perspective

This is probably wishful thinking, but I figured I'd ask and hope to get lucky:

I have an Eclipse RCP app with some complicated layouts. Is there some way to manually layout the views/editors in the perspective and export that layout back into the the plugins, so I don't have to twiddle every plugin.xml file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Window Builder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro) it can even layout Eclipse perspectives.